# inside ng-repeat, all the switch button status changing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have used `ng-repeat` to show multiple content and I have created on/off button for the content. 
When i select off only that particular button should be off, but instead of this all the button's state is changing.

```
<div ng-repeat="settings in Notification.preferences | orderBy:'order'">
    <p class="notification-heading">{{settings.code}}</p>
    <div class="notification-methods">
        <span>{{settings.methods[0]}}</span>
        <div class="notification-on-off-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-toggle-on active" ng-if="status == true" ng-click="changeStatus()"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-rotate-180 inactive" ng-if="status == false" ng-click="changeStatus()"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="notification-methods">
        <span>{{settings.methods[1]}}</span>
        <div class="notification-on-off-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-toggle-on active" ng-if="status == true" ng-click="changeStatus()"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-rotate-180 inactive"  ng-if="status == false" ng-click="changeStatus()"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module(notification_settings_app_name)
.controller("notificationSettingsCtrl", ["$scope", '$rootScope', 'notificationSettingsService', function($scope, $rootScope, notificationSettingsService) {

    $scope.status = true;
    $scope.changeStatus = function(){
        $scope.status = !$scope.status;
    }
    notificationSettingsService.NotificationGetContent().then(function(response){ debugger;
        $scope.Notification = response;
    });

}]);
```

Json Data:

```
{
"status" : true,
"exception" : null,
"data": {
    "methods": ["SMS","EMAIL","PUSH"],
    "preferences": [
        {
            "code": "Example 1",
            "name": "Example 1 content",
            "methods": ["SMS", "EMAIL"]
        },
        {
            "code": "Example 2",
            "name": "Example 2 content",
            "methods": ["SMS", "EMAIL"]
        },
        {
            "code": "Example 3",
            "name": "Example 3 content",
            "methods": ["SMS", "EMAIL"]
        },
        {
            "code": "Example 4",
            "name": "Example 4 content",
            "methods": ["SMS", "EMAIL"]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Is there any way to restrict all the on/off button state getting changed? Only the button which is clicked that button state should be changed? 
I was looking for $this but no success.

Sorry for delay forgot to add one more requirement, need to send response to url in below format also. Suppose if example 1 method email option is turned to off then response should be send as false and vice versa.

```
PUT : http://URL
  {
    "category": "Example 1",
    "method": "EMAIL",
    "enabled": false
  }
```

[Plunker working link](https://plnkr.co/edit/pIBjao0ujuAzyJGZSPfU?p=preview)

Comment: I wonder if the status on/off corresponding to attribute in the `settings` something like `settings.enabled.`, by the way status for each button would be independently and identified by the object you repeat with , then you need to set the button switch according to it. could you provide the simple data,

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the data, Now I can see, I believe that `status` is mean something on server-side like data was found, and `setting.methods` is what you want to on/off and it is array and according to my assumptions I did this.

Note: I changes the span place just for fun and [here plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Em272EsuZHw0wzwTsf1R?p=preview)

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.status = true;
  $scope.changeStatus = function(settings){
        $scope.status = !$scope.status;
  };
  
  $scope.addMethod = function(setting, method){
    setting.methods.push(method);
  }
  
  $scope.removeMethod = function(setting, method){
    var index = setting.methods.indexOf(method);
    setting.methods.splice(index,1);
  }
    
    
  var response = {
        "status" : true,
        "exception" : null,
        "data": {
            "methods": ["SMS","EMAIL","PUSH"],
            "preferences": [
                {
                    "code": "Example 1",
                    "name": "Example 1 content",
                    "methods": ["SMS", "EMAIL"]
                },
                {
                    "code": "Example 2",
                    "name": "Example 2 content",
                    "methods": ["SMS", "EMAIL"]
                },
                {
                    "code": "Example 3",
                    "name": "Example 3 content",
                    "methods": ["SMS", "EMAIL"]
                },
                {
                    "code": "Example 4",
                    "name": "Example 4 content",
                    "methods": ["SMS", "EMAIL"]
                }
            ]
        }
        };
  $scope.Notification = response.data;
    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.2" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link data-require="fontawesome@*" data-semver="4.5.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
  <script data-require="jquery@1.10.0" data-semver="1.10.0" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.1/js/tether.min.js"></script>


  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.2" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <div ng-repeat="settings in Notification.preferences | orderBy:'order'">
      <p class="notification-heading">{{settings.code}}</p>
      <div ng-repeat='method in Notification.methods track by $index' class="notification-methods">

        <div class="notification-on-off-icon">
          <span>{{method}}</span>
          <i class="fa fa-toggle-on active" ng-if="settings.methods.indexOf(method) != -1" ng-click="removeMethod(settings, method)"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-rotate-180 inactive" ng-if="settings.methods.indexOf(method) == -1" ng-click="addMethod(settings, method)"></i>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Note: If you can (have permission to) change the incoming JSON structure then I have a cleaner approach for this problem (the below solution works but can be improved if you can alter the JSON structure).

This is because your `$scope.status` is common for all not for individual preference. Consider this example:

```js
var app = angular.module("sa", []);

app.controller("FooController", function($scope) {
  $scope.changeStatus = function(settings, method) {
    settings[method] = !settings[method];
  };

  $scope.isActive = function(settings, method) {
    return settings[method];
  };

  $scope.Notification = {
    "status": true,
    "exception": null,
    "data": {
      "methods": ["SMS", "EMAIL", "PUSH"],
      "preferences": [{
        "code": "Example 1",
        "name": "Example 1 content",
        "methods": ["SMS", "EMAIL"]
      }, {
        "code": "Example 2",
        "name": "Example 2 content",
        "methods": ["SMS", "EMAIL"]
      }, {
        "code": "Example 3",
        "name": "Example 3 content",
        "methods": ["SMS", "EMAIL"]
      }, {
        "code": "Example 4",
        "name": "Example 4 content",
        "methods": ["SMS", "EMAIL"]
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T8Gy5hrqNKT+hzMclPo118YTQO6cYprQmhrYwIiQ/3axmI1hQomh7Ud2hPOy8SP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div ng-app="sa" ng-controller="FooController" class="container">

  <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="settings in Notification.data.preferences | orderBy:'order'">
    <p class="notification-heading panel-heading">{{settings.code}}</p>
    <div class="notification-methods panel-body">
      <span>{{settings.methods[0]}}</span>
      
      <span class="notification-on-off-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-rotate-180 inactive" ng-class="{'fa-toggle-on active': !isActive(settings, settings.methods[0]), 'fa-toggle-off inactive': isActive(settings, settings.methods[0])}" ng-click="changeStatus(settings, settings.methods[0])"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="notification-methods panel-body">
      <span>{{settings.methods[1]}}</span>
      
      <span class="notification-on-off-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-rotate-180 inactive" ng-class="{'fa-toggle-on active': !isActive(settings, settings.methods[1]), 'fa-toggle-off inactive': isActive(settings, settings.methods[1])}" ng-click="changeStatus(settings, settings.methods[1])"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry cant change json response.

Comment: I have used your method it is working thanks did some change, ng-repeat="settings in pgxNotification.preferences | orderBy:'order'"

Comment: But now how to capture value true and false, to send use put and send json response. Sorry for not updating this before.